# Conditionally passing options to a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.fn.demo = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        opacity: 50,
        width: '250px',
        height: '100px',
        color: 'red'
    }
  }
```

**Is there any way to conditionally pass options to a function, like such:**

```
$().demo({
opacity: 60,
if (div.length){
    width: '350px'
}
height: '100px'
});
```

Just curious what would be the best way to handle a situation where you may want to pass different options depending on circumstances. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's simple enough you can use the [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

```
$().demo({
    opacity: 60,
    width: div.length ? '350px' : '250px',
    height: '100px'
});
```

If it's more complicated you should just compose the parameter object outside of the function call.

```
var parameters = {
    opacity: 60,
    height: '100px'
};
if(div.length)
    parameters.width = '350px';
$().demo(parameters);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$.fn.demo = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        opacity: 50,
        width: '250px',
        height: '100px',
        color: 'red'
    };
    options || (options = {});
    defaults = $.extend(defaults, options);
    ... function body...
}
```

When you use extend, it overwrites defaults and adds any arbitrary data, if it's present.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution, as it will not override any options if they are already present.

Comment: I don't think the question was about jQuery plugin development but about how to pass parameters to jQuery functions.

Comment: You pass them same way: `$().yourFunc({param: 'value', foo: 'Bar'})`

Comment: `$.extend` accepts `undefined` at one of its arguments; no need for `||`.